# Prove that for any prime $p>2$ the sum if written as a rational number $a/b$, has the property that $p|a$.

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Prove that for any prime $p>2$ the sum

$$\frac{1}{1^3}+\frac{1}{2^3}+\dots+\frac{1}{(p-1)^3}$$

if written as a rational number $a/b$, has the property that $p|a$.

Comment: What is the context? What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Generalization**

For $p=3$, the claim is trivial.  For a prime integer $p>3$, the sum $$\sum_{x\in\mathbb{F}_p}\,x^k$$
is equal to $0$ for all $k=0,1,2,\ldots,p-2$ (where $0^0:=1$).  In particular, when $k:=p-4<p-2$, we have
$$0=\sum_{x\in\mathbb{F}_p}\,x^{p-4}=\sum_{x\in\mathbb{F}_p^\times}\,\frac{1}{x^3}\,.$$
In general, if a prime number $p$ and an integer $k$ satisfy $p-1>k>0$, then $$\sum_{x\in\mathbb{F}_p^\times}\,\frac{1}{x^k}=0\,.$$

---

**Alternative, Elementary Solution**

For $j=1,2,\ldots,\frac{p-1}{2}$ and for an ***odd*** integer $k>0$, we have that $$\frac{1}{j^k}+\frac{1}{(p-j)^k}=\frac{p\,a_j}{b_j}$$
for some $a_j,b_j\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0}$ with $\gcd\left(a_j,b_j\right)=1$ and $p\nmid b_j$.